# Qual a diferença entre servidor web e servidor de aplicação?

Tags: terminologia, webserver, servidor-de-aplicação

Qual a diferença entre **servidor web** e **servidor de aplicação**? Onde cada um é/deve ser utilizado? Há alguma interação entre eles (um software pode utilizar as 2 tecnologias em conjunto)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Um servidor de aplicação é simplesmente um servidor, no sentido da arquitetura cliente-servidor: um processo que atende um ou mais aplicativos clientes que lhe enviam requisições. Coloque para rodar um processo que abre uma porta para atender conexões TCP ou UDP, e *voilà!*, você tem um servidor de aplicação.

No nosso mundo Web precisamos de vários tipos de servidores. Um que entenda requisições feitas no protocolo HTTP, por exemplo, para se comunicar com clientes espalhados pela Internet. Minimamente esse servidor pode ser capaz de servir dados estáticos, como páginas HTML estáticas, arquivos e imagens. É o chamado "Servidor Web". Exemplo: o "Apache HTTP Server" ou simplesmente Apache.

Mas só isso não é suficiente. É comum precisarmos que ele sirva dados dinâmicos, como páginas HTML personalizadas, cadeias de bytes, arquivos e até imagens construídos com base em informação variável como os parâmetros da própria requisição ou no resultado de uma consulta a um banco de dados (este por si só um servidor de aplicação também, como o @Maniero disse, só que especializado em armazenar dados estruturados).

Uma forma de resolver isso é implementar um servidor Web que tenha comportamento dinâmico. Não é muito prático: dependendo do porte dos serviços que ele se propuser a prestar vamos ter que nos dedicar a implementar muita lógica, digamos, de "infraestrutura" para o construirmos, como por exemplo separar as requisições em threads para economizar recursos e melhorar performance, lógica de segurança (autenticação, autorização) preferencialmente declarativa (isto é, baseada por exemplo em um arquivo-texto que alguém possa modificar sem ter que recompilar o código todo do servidor), comportamento de filtragem de requisições (por exemplo, o comportamento de sempre autenticar as requisições destinadas a atender usuários logados antes de executar sua lógica), *logging*, a própria lógica de se interpretar uma página dinâmica e gerar o HTML (isso tudo eu estou descaradamente pegando do livro *Head First Servlets & JSP* que explica por quais razões é melhor fazer de forma diferente, usando um Container).

Outra forma de fazer é delegar a parte dinâmica para *scripts* escritos em Perl, PHP ou alguma outra linguagem. Também pode bater de frente com algumas das limitações citadas, inclusive a de abrir um processo separado para cada requisição, o que é mais custoso que usar *threads*.

Outra forma é usando um Container (também chamado *Web Container* ou *Servlet Container*), que é a solução proposta pelas tecnologias Java e que eu conheço melhor. Ele é um servidor também, que recebe as requisições de um servidor HTTP (vulgo servidor Web, lembra?) e cuida de toda a lógica de infraestrutura anteriormente citada, deixando você livre para implementar somente a lógica de negócio que interessa à sua aplicação específica. O Container repassa as requisições para Servlets, que são basicamente classes Java, e cada Servlet executa a requisição em uma *thread*. Você pode programar um Servlet para atender requisições de login, outro para incluir itens em um pedido, outro para excluir pedidos, e assim por diante.

Isso também costuma ser chamado de "Servidor de Aplicação", no sentido que eu acredito que você tinha em mente quando fez sua pergunta. Ele é composto por um servidor Web, e também por um servidor extra, o Container, que é responsável pela geração de conteúdo dinâmico.  Então podemos dizer que nessa segunda definição de servidor de aplicação, o dito servidor de aplicação **contém** um servidor Web.

(Note que nessa arquitetura combinada não é preciso que seja um servidor Web, nem que o protocolo seja HTTP; mas é o mais comum no mundo Web).

Exemplo de servidor de aplicação: Apache Tomcat (servidor web Apache + *container* de *servlets*). Nota: o Tomcat também tem um servidor HTTP alternativo chamado "Apache Tomcat HTTP Server".

No Java, uma aplicação destinada a rodar em um *container* (que costuma ser chamada "aplicação web") é um arquivo .WAR (abreviatura de "Web ARchive") que é basicamente composto pelos Servlets que o *container* irá executar mais algum conteúdo estático (imagens, arquivos de configuração, etc).

Comment: Piovezan, você disse o seguinte: "Coloque para rodar um processo que abre uma porta para atender conexões TCP ou UDP, e voilà!, você tem um servidor de aplicação. "
É de responsabilidade do sistema operacional tratar os protocolos na camada de transporte (TCP e UDP), sendo assim o correto não seria dizer que o servidor web é responsável por atender requisições HTTP ao invés de TCP e UDP?. Não é cargo do S.O analisar os protocolos na camada de transporte e após isso delegar o controle dos dados para o servidor web que irá analisar o conteúdo da requisição?.

Comment: @FelipeCanatto O que você disse está correto. Quando falo atender conexões TCP ou UDP eu deveria falar conexões com stream sockets ou datagram sockets. O tipo de socket que o servidor abre vai determinar o protocolo da camada de transporte que ele usa por baixo (isto é, as garantias quanto a recebimento e ordem de chegada dos pacotes). Que ficam a cargo do S.O. como você falou. O servidor web, que geralmente abre stream sockets, trata os bytes recebidos como requisições do protocolo de camada de aplicação HTTP.

Answer (score 6):

Um *web server* é um *application server* para atender necessidades *web*. Por exemplo, ao contrário do que muita gente pensa, o IIS da Microsoft é um *application server*, sendo que uma das suas funções é servir web.

Um servidor de aplicação "hospeda" processos de um sistema que permitem clientes fazerem requisições e receberem respostas.

Fica óbvio que o servidor web precisa trabalhar com protocolos HTTP e derivados. Ele tem algumas funções pré-definidas que só fazem, ou pelo menos fazem muito sentido para o fluxo normal de soluções web. Em geral várias das tarefas que um servidor web precisa são as mesmas de qualquer outro tipo de servidor aplicação, incluindo atividades de acesso à banco de dados e/ou delegação de parte da tarefa para um mecanismo fora do servidor em si (chamada de um executável ou *script*).

Você pode ter um *web server* que delega o processamento específico para um *application server* sem especialização (ou não) que delega a manipulação e armazenamento de dados para um *database server*.

Então algumas pessoas podem usar o termo *application server* apenas para o *host* da lógica de negócios (roda o ambiente da aplicação no geral). Alguns vão considerar então que todo *web server* é um *application server* neste sentido, já que ele executa lógica de negócios através de *scripts*.

Outros consideram que apenas o conteúdo estático é o que o servidor web trata e qualquer conteúdo dinâmico faz parte do servidor de aplicação.

As pessoas esquecem que HTTP é apenas uma aplicação normal com regras específicas.

É basicamente isto. Eu sei que alguns *stacks* de tecnologias preferem usar definições próprias, mas as acho restritivas. Aprender da forma apresentada por uma tecnologia é seguir a receita de bolo imposta e algumas pessoas se prendem à isto. Em alguns casos eu vejo o termo *application server* sendo usado para um conjunto de serviços disponíveis. Está certo, aquilo é um *app server* com algumas funções definidas.

Não gosto, por exemplo, das [definições dadas no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/936197/221800). Eles se prendem à tecnologias específicas, consideram o termo como o mercado usa e não como sugere a computação como um todo.

Você pode escrever um servidor de aplicação com poucas linhas de código. Depende dos requisitos. Um servidor web, por exemplo já não é tão simples (até dá para fazer um simples, mas será bem rudimentar e perigoso de uso externo). Existem requisitos definidos que não são nada simples. Mas também não digo que seja tão difícil escrever um.

Como complemento podemos dizer que um *database server* é um *application server* específico para dar acesso à dados armazenados.

E assim por diante. Um é especialização do outro.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Pra ter -1 aqui, ou tem alguém de sacanagem, ou alguém que não entende realmente do assunto (ou as duas coisas). Se for sacanagem, não dá pra discutir. Se não foi de sacanagem, sugeriria a pessoa realmente sair da caixinha e ver que o mundo é bem maior do que o que ela "acha" que é um servidor de aplicação.

Comment: O SOpt tá assim, as pessoas aprendem a receita de bolo e acham que quem não segue ela está errado. Não tem muito o que fazer, as pessoas gostam de se limitar.

Comment: nesse caso eu juro que eu preferiria que fosse de sacanagem (se bem que prejudica a comunidade, e não você, então é ruim de qq jeito), pq se realmente a pessoa votou contra pq não concorda com o conteúdo, é sinal que as coisas realmente vão mal. Birra me parece menos danoso do que voto religioso.

Comment: Acho que você tem razão, observando algumas coisas, parece ter sido sacanagem mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Um resposta em poucas palavras seria:

- Um Servidor de Aplicação serve processos que permitem clientes fazerem requisições e receberem respostas;
- Um Servidor Web é um servidor de aplicação especializado para atender as necessidades Web. Ou seja, precisa trabalhar com protocolos HTTP e derivados.

Assim sendo, o Servidor Web trabalha através do protocolo HTTP, enquanto o Servidor de Aplicação não está restrito a ele, podendo suportar outros protocolos, como RMI / RPC.