# Relação entre JDK e as distribuições do Java

Tags: java

As três distribuições do Java são: SE, EE, ME (tem tb o JAVAFX). Em todos os lugares que já vi o pessoal não baixa a versão em si, apenas o JDK.

O JDK já vem com todas estas versões? Ou apenas a SE e, se eu quiser usar EE ou ME, devo instala-las como se fossem plugins?

Answer (score 1):

SE, ME e EE são as três plataformas da linguagem Java. Você deve encará-las como especificações, algo intangível. Se você baixá-las você receberá, na verdade, um documento HTML ou PDF especificando o comportamento e contéudo de uma dessas plataformas. Por exemplo, esse é o link da especificação da plataforma Java SE [Java SE 8 Edition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html).

O quê você normalmente baixa é a implementação daquela especificação. Como você mesmo citou JDK na sua pergunta, indo no site da oracle para baixar a implementação do JDK feita por eles, perceba o seguinte texto traduzido [jdk oracle](https://www.oracle.com/ca-en/java/technologies/downloads/):

> O Java 17 LTS é a versão de suporte de longo prazo mais recente para a **plataforma Java SE**. Os binários JDK 19 e JDK 17 são gratuitos para uso em produção e redistribuídos gratuitamente, de acordo com os termos e condições isentos de taxas da Oracle.

Ou seja, **baixar o JDK quer dizer na verdade baixar uma implementação do Java SE**. Dentro do JDK, teremos a máquina virtual Java e todos os programas necessários para o desenvolvimento de uma aplicação.

O Java EE é uma especificação voltada para aplicações empresariais. Um exemplo da especificação Java EE seria [Java EE 8](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=366). Uma implementação bastante comum seria os servidores Apache Tomcat e Wildfly. A parte principal pra entender aqui é que **eles também são aplicações Java**. Eles irão primeiramente popular o classpath com a implementação do Java EE que eles possuem e rodarão a sua aplicação em seguida.

Dessa maneira, sua aplicação terá acesso a pacotes que pertencem a especificação Java EE (como por exemplo [Servlet](https://JavaFX%20was%20intended%20to%20replace%20Swing%20as%20the%20standard%20GUI%20library%20for%20Java%20SE)). Outra coisa importante notar aqui é que diferente da especificação Java SE no qual todos as JVMs implementam a especificação integralmente, o mesmo não ocorre no Java EE. Tomcat, por exemplo, só implementa algumas partes da especificação do Java EE, enquanto que o Wildfly já implementa a especificação integralmente. Vale a pena entender um pouco melhor essa diferença entre Contâiner de Servlet e Servidor de Aplicação. [Servidor Web vs Servidor de Aplicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122589/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-servidor-web-e-servidor-de-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o) (Contâiner de Servlet também pode ser chamado de Servidor Web, porém o primeiro termo é mais comum)

E, finalmente, Java ME. É a plataforma Java voltada para dispositivos móveis e sistemas embarcados. Uma implementação, por exemplo, seria a da Oracle [Oracle Java ME](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-embedded-java-me-downloads.html).

Em resumo, Java EE pode ser visto como uma extensão do Java SE. Tudo que contém no Java SE estará contido no Java EE. O mesmo não pode ser dito do Java ME, algumas coisas do Java SE muito provavelmente não estarão presentes no Java ME. E, por último, JavaFX é uma biblioteca de interface gráfica que está contida dentro do Java SE.